# Not using port in the url

Tags: spring-boot, iptables, tomcat8

I use spring boot (tomcat embedded) and ssl.

Actually, I need to type the port (8443) in the url to be able to access web applicaiton.

How to be able to use domnain name only?

Something like
https://www.bob.com

instead of

https://www.bob.com:8443/

Edit

```
@Bean
public EmbeddedServletContainerFactory servletContainer() {
    TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory tomcat
            = new TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory() {

        @Override
        protected void postProcessContext(Context context) {
            SecurityConstraint securityConstraint = new SecurityConstraint();
            securityConstraint.setUserConstraint("CONFIDENTIAL");
            SecurityCollection collection = new SecurityCollection();
            collection.addPattern("/*");
            securityConstraint.addCollection(collection);
            context.addConstraint(securityConstraint);
        }
    };
    tomcat.addAdditionalTomcatConnectors(createHttpConnector());
    return tomcat;
}

private Connector createHttpConnector() {
    Connector connector
            = new Connector("org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol");
    connector.setScheme("http");
    connector.setSecure(false);
    connector.setPort(8080);
    connector.setRedirectPort(8443);
    return connector;
}
```

now not need to type port

but if it type bob.com, browser convert to

bob.com:8443

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Default port used by browsers for HTTP is 80 and HTTPS is 443. If you run your application on 443 (since you are using HTTPS), you don't have to use the port number, browser will automatically reroute your URL. To change the port number in you spring-boot applicatioN specify `server.port` property in bootstrap.yml.

```
server:
  port: 443
```

Comment: ok so instead of using 8443  (who seem default for tomcat), i could use directly 443.... or doing a rediction 8443 to 443 with iptable?

Comment: Right. 8443 is the default set by spring-boot (not my Tomcat) for your application. You can override them as I mentioned above. Then you don't have to do anything. Just type the url without port.

Comment: The only thing you should be aware of with this solution is that on *nix systems you'll need root rights to bind to ports below 1024.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?

```
String webPort = System.getenv("PORT");

    if(webPort == null || webPort.isEmpty()) {
        webPort = "8080";
    }
```